# Creating a Dictionary from a .txt File in Python

Tags: python, file, dictionary

I am trying to create a dictionary from a txt file "PortList.txt" with information in similar format to below, but keep getting the error "TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'"

> TCP  0  Reserved
>
> TCP  1  Port Service Multiplexer
>
> TCP  2  Management Utility

The Key will be the "TCP" and "0" while the value is "Reserved"

My opening code is:

```
portDictionary = {}
with open('PortList.txt', 'r') as infile:
    for nextLine in infile:   
        lineList = nextLine.split()
        keys = [lineList[0], lineList[1]]
        values = [lineList[2]] 
        #this won't cover all of the words for the value, but for the test it's just for the first word
        portDictionary[keys] = values
```

Comment: You are not posting the part of your code generating the error.

Comment: If by `The Key will be the "TCP" and "0"` you mean `['TCP', '0']`, you can't do that. As the error says, you can't use a list as a key. You can use a tuple, though.

Comment: Your edit reveals that you are doing exactly what I thought you were.

Comment: Briefly: change the outer square brackets into parentheses when you create `keys`.

Comment: when I do that I get "IndexError: list index out of range" for the `keys`

Comment: Don't try to split blank lines.